# Unable to populate data for my AutoCompleteExtender for the TextBox in my Asp.Net page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

hi i am unbale to populate data to an textbox using autocompleteextender, the data is being fetch from the database. i a m giving the code of mine below. Any suggestions are welcome. 
ASP.Net code:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>       
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" UseContextKey="true" runat="server" CompletionInterval="10" TargetControlID="TextBox1" ServiceMethod="GetValues" MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="4">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static List<string> GetValues(string prefixText,int count)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=172.22.1.189;Initial Catalog=M1022779;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "select * from dept where dname like '%'+@Name+'%'";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    //Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0][0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        lst.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: Add ServicePath to AutoCompleteExtender  **ServicePath=test.asmx"**

Comment: i am no using webservices

Comment: the both are in a same file

Comment: The WebMethod Should return an array of strings!

Comment: no luck with all these things

Comment: please can any one help with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AutoCompleteExtender :

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" UseContextKey="true" runat="server" CompletionInterval="10" TargetControlID="TextBox1" ServiceMethod="GetValues" MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="4">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

`**UseContextKey="true"`

Your method should have `string contextKey`:

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetValues(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
```

or set `UseContextKey="false"`